Program 'flutter.bat' failed to run
Iam trying to run any command of flutter in terminal of vscode it gives me this error and when i try to run in cmd then command prompt automatically closed.I have tried many things upto now.

I tried to run command to accept android license.
I tried by disabling the antivirus as i found in some youtube video and stack overflow.

Nothings seems working. What can do now?


Follow some steps to resolve this issue... verify flutter SDK location, restart IDE and Terminal, update flutter, reinstall flutter.

@DroidFlutter I already followed all these steps but didn't resolve my issue.

Make sure that flutter is in path, also, you're missing a space between the word doctor and --android-licenses

flutter is in path. and also space in the command is not the problem. even if type flutter only or flutter --version same error occured.
